# Can't connect to kubernetes API from inside the cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, java-11, minikube

I'm trying to use the [fabric8io/kubernetes-client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) in a simple example on my local minikube 
cluster where I get an IP of a pod

```
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.ConfigBuilder;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient;

public class PodLogExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String podName = "some-pod-name-jnfen3";
    String namespace = "default";
    String master = "https://localhost:32780/";

    Config config = new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl(master).build();
    KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config);
    String podIP = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withName(podName).get().getStatus().getPodIP();
    System.out.println("Pod IP is: " + podIP);
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    client.close();
  }
}
```

`some-pod-name-jnfen3` is a name of a pod which finished execution and visible if I execute `kubectl get pods`.

`https://localhost:32780/` is a kubernetes API host which I get from `kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.clusters[?(@.name==\"minikube\")].cluster.server}"`.

- minikube has only 1 node.
- fabric8io/kubernetes-client version is 4.9.1
- Java 11

I deploy this code as a Job on the same cluster as the `some-pod-name-jnfen3`. Here's the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [some-pod-name-jnfen3]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:225)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:168)
    at PodLogExample.main(PodLogExample.java:16)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:32780
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:249)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:258)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:469)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:430)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:395)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:376)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:845)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:214)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
    ... 34 more
```

For some reason it can't connect to the kubernetes API host.

How can I fix it?

#### UPDATE

If I don't pass the `config` to the client, it gets the correct master IP and then fails with the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://10.96.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/some-pod-name-jnfen3. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods "some-pod-name-jnfen3" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default".
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:568)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:505)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:471)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:430)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:395)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:376)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:845)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:214)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:168)
    at PodLogExample.main(PodLogExample.java:17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.clusters[?(@.name==\"minikube\")].cluster.server}"` returns the relative IP. It is different for the Pod.

Not passing `config` will make the library find the correct IP.

Also a new service account should be created and set in the job.yaml.

The `default` service account doesn't have permissions to fetch k8s entities.

Related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/2183)

Answer (score 0):

It’s localhost from the point of view of your laptop, from inside the cluster it is not. Use the InClusterConfig helpers instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I use `InClusterConfig` here

Comment: It’s the default with fabric, just don’t pass in anything I think.